# Do I need the the Maven wrapper for submodules?

Tags: maven

If I have a parent Maven project that contains the Maven wrapper files, is there any reason to also including the wrappers in the submodules of this project? Does it really matter? Any possible side effects of doing this I need to look out for? I only plan on running Maven commands from the parent project, but some day I may want to break the submodules up into their own separate projects.

Edit: To be clear, I'm talking about `mvnw`, `mvnw.cmd`, and the `.mvn` directory

Comment: What do you mean by "Maven wrapper file"?

Comment: @JFMeier `mvnw`, `mvnw.cmd`, and the `.mvn` directory

Answer (score 0):

The Maven Wrapper is only needed on the root level the project. The intention is to define a the version which will be used for building the project by downloading it automatically.

If you later decide to split up the project this would result in creating separated repositories (Git) and this means you have for each of such projects an other root which mean there it would make sense to have the maven wrapper.